# No se ejecuta programa en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Estoy programando en python el uso del sensor supersónico HY-SRF05 usando una Raspberry Pi 3. El programa no ma da error, pero no muestra la distancia al ejecutarse, si le quito la clase y los métodos y dejo solamente el código líneal, funciona correctamente pero requiero el uso de métodos por cuestiones de trabajo futuro. Necesito que se muestre la distancia. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import mysql.connector
import requests
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO   
import time                

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)    
GPIO_TRIGGER = 25          
GPIO_ECHO    = 7          
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER,GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO,GPIO.IN)     
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER,False)   

class Execute:

    def ObtenerDistancia(self):
        temperature = 20
        speedSound = 33100 + (0.6*temperature)
        GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER,GPIO.OUT)  
        GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO,GPIO.IN)     
        GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
        time.sleep(0.5)# Allow module to settle
        GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
        time.sleep(0.00001)# Wait 10us
        GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
        start = time.time()
        while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
            start = time.time()
        while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1:
            stop = time.time()
        elapsed = stop-start
        distance = elapsed * speedSound
        distance = distance / 2
        print("Distance : {0:5.1f}".format(distance))
        GPIO.cleanup()
        return distance


x = Execute()
xDis = x.ObtenerDistancia

while True:
    print (xDis())
```

Mi código "lineal":

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO_TRIGGER = 23
GPIO_ECHO    = 24
temperature = 20
speedSound = 33100 + (0.6*temperature)

print("Ultrasonic Measurement")
print("Speed of sound is",speedSound/100,"m/s at ",temperature,"deg")
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER,GPIO.OUT)  
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO,GPIO.IN)      
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
time.sleep(0.5)# Allow module to settle
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)# Wait 10us
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
start = time.time()
while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
    start = time.time()
while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1:
    stop = time.time()
elapsed = stop-start
distance = elapsed * speedSound
distance = distance / 2
print("Distance : {0:5.1f}".format(distance))
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Hola Juan ¿Qué quieres decir con que no funciona? ¿Muestra alguna excepción?¿Cómo ejecutas el método? Debes crear una instancia de tu clase (`obj = Execute()`) y después llamar al método (`obj.ObtenerDistancia()`) o directamente `Execute().ObtenerDistancia()`

Comment: ¿Puedes poner también el código "lineal" que dices que sí que funciona? ¿Se trata simplemente de las mismas instrucciones que hay dentro de `ObtenerDistancia()`? ¿Las ejecutas también en un bucle infinito? A priori no en la implementación con clases nada que explique por qué no funciona así, pero sí sin la clase.

Comment: FJSevilla no da ningún error, y de echo hasta abajo hago lo que me propones de crear la instancia de clase. Si le asigno que sólo retorne un valor sin hacer el proceso de lectura de datos, funciona correctamente, el problema es cuando hago meto la lectura de los datos del sensor

Comment: abulfia, listo ahí está

Comment: El codigo lineal no usa los mismos valores de `GPIO_TRIGGER` y `GPIO_ECHO` ¿tendrá algo qué ver? Desde el punto de vista de python, no debería haber diferencia de comportamiento por encerrar el código en un método...